# Twitter Bootstrap Pulsate in a different colour?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter bootstrap. My button's class is usually `btn btn-default` and I want to change the class to `btn btn-success` so the button is green. Then a nice little 3 pulsates and then return to default colour.

The best I've gotten so far is:

```
$('#myBtn').removeClass('btn btn-default').addClass('btn btn-success');

for(i=0;i<3;i++) {
    $(#myBtn).fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
  }

$('#myBtn').removeClass('btn btn-success').addClass('btn btn-default');
```

The problem with this is that it just instantly changes the colour back to default while the animation continues. Any ideas? I've looked at JQuery Color and there isn't anything quite like it off the shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the animate function.

Here is a sample with only one "fadding"

http://jsfiddle.net/wVmG7/1/

```
$( "#btnTest" ).click(function(){
  $('#myBtn').removeClass('btn btn-default').addClass('btn btn-success');
  $( "#myBtn" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.3
  }, 1000, function() {
    $( this ).after($( "#myBtn" ).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000, function() {
            $( this ).after( $( "#myBtn" ).removeClass('btn btn-success').addClass('btn btn-default') )
    })
    )
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The fades happen asynchronously so you need to wait until they finish before transitioning again. Instead of a loop I think you can cheat by chaining together liike this, and doing your last step upon completion of the last delay. Note that 'slow' = 600 ms transition, hence the 1200 values...

```
$('#myBtn').removeClass('btn btn-default').addClass('btn btn-success');

$('#myBtn').fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0).delay(1200)
         .fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0).delay(1200)
         .fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0).delay(1200, 
         function() {
           $('#myBtn').removeClass('btn btn-success').addClass('btn btn-default');
         });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8C3SA/

If you want something a bit neater (in the form of a jQuery plugin), check out @Doug Neiner's answer here: [jQuery: fade div in and out multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094621/jquery-fade-div-in-and-out-multiple-times)